# Distillery post start hook fail due to genserver not being started

Tags: elixir, gen-server, distillery

I have a Genserver which is needed to run before I can seed data. Adding a post start hook fails on distillery release with an error  that my genserver is not running.

```
(exit) exited in: GenServer.call(MyApp.NumberHelper, {:number, #Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: .....
```

This genserver is a child of my application, the releaseTasks file is the same as the one on docs https://hexdocs.pm/distillery/guides/running_migrations.html

How can I start the genserver so my seeds won't fail?

This genserver works as expected on production, development and test environment. The only problem occurs when I try to run seeds as a post start hook after starting the application

Comment: Does your `GenServer` uses `handle_continue/2` deferred initialization? Is it a part of your application supervision tree?

Comment: It is part of the supervision tree. No explicit `handle_continue/2` defined by me

Comment: I am not sure at what exact moment you call this seeding, but adding [`Application.ensure_all_started(:my_app)`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html?#ensure_all_started/2) _before_ seeding should probably help.

Comment: Doing that shows an error that the address is already in use.